# Image Transform not working

Tags: image-transforms

I have set transforms in admin but when I call those transforms in Twig nothing happens. 'getUrl('thumb')' shows blank in return although when calling like

```
 <img src="{{ asset.getUrl('thumb') }}"
  width="{{ asset.getWidth('thumb') }}"
  height="{{ asset.getHeight('thumb') }}">
```

width and height have values but url is blank.
Anyone have idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the targeting of the asset itself.

If you are calling an Entry's asset from a field that expects one single image you can write:

```
{% set img = entry.fieldName.one() %}
<img 
   src="{{ img.getUrl('thumb') }}" 
   width="{{ img.getWidth('thumb') }}" 
   height="{{ img.getHeight('thumb') }}" />
```

If you are doing this in a for loop, or your field allows more than one image to be selected you can write:

```
{% for item in entry.fieldName %}
    {% set img = item.one() %}
    <img 
       src="{{ img.getUrl('thumb') }}" 
       width="{{ img.getWidth('thumb') }}" 
       height="{{ img.getHeight('thumb') }}" />
{% endfor %}
```